# How to restart a failed pod in kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have 3 nodes in kubernetes cluster. I create a `daemonset` and deployed it in all the 3 devices. This `daemonset` created 3 pods and they were successfully running. But for some reasons, one of the pod failed.

I need to know how can we restart this pod  without affecting other pods in the daemon set, also without creating any other daemon set deployment?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "deployed it in all the 3 devices". Normally you create a daemonset with e.g. kubectl through the API server and then kubernetes takes care of creating pods on each node (device). The failed pod should also automatically get replaced by a new one. Could you please add the yaml definition of your daemonset to this question? And the output of `kubectl describe pod` for the failed pod would help. You can list terminated pods with `kubectl get pod -a`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`kubectl delete pod <podname>` it will delete this one pod and Deployment/StatefulSet/ReplicaSet/DaemonSet will reschedule a new one in its place

Comment: You can use selectors to delete all pods: `kubectl delete pod -l app=my-app`

Comment: If you get `Error from server (NotFound): pods <podname> not found` I realised I also needed to add namespace `kubectl delete pod <podname> -n <namespace>`

Answer (score 84):

There are other possibilities to acheive what you want:

- Just use `rollout` command

  `kubectl rollout restart deployment mydeploy`
- You can set some environment variable which will force your deployment pods to restart:

  `kubectl set env deployment mydeploy DEPLOY_DATE="$(date)"`
- You can scale your deployment to zero, and then back to some positive value

```
    kubectl scale deployment mydeploy --replicas=0
    kubectl scale deployment mydeploy --replicas=1
```

Answer (score 12):

Just for others reading this...

A better solution (IMHO) is to implement a [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/) that will force the pod to restart the container if it fails the probe test.

This is a great feature K8s offers out of the box. This is auto healing.

Also look into the pod [lifecycle docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/).

Comment: It will restart one container, but won't restart a pod.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl -n <namespace> delete pods --field-selector=status.phase=Failed`

I think the above command is quite useful when you want to restart 1 or more failed pods :D

And we don't need to care about name of the failed pod.